# MySQL Missing Colon

Tags: mysql, exception, syntax-error

So I just started to use MySQL but I had used Oracle before, and I loved Oracle, but MySQL not so much and I'm trying to create a Procedure that throws an exception, but I don't get understand how to do this in MySQL because in Oracle it was as simple as just doing:

```
exception
 when others then
   raise_application_error(-20001, 'An errror was ecountered = '||SQLCODE||'- ERROR-'||SQLERRM);
```

SO I looked for a tutorial of how to do this in MySQL and I tried to use it but I can't get it to work in mySQL because it always says "Syntax Error; Missing Colon" and I don't understand what is the error.

Here is the Procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$ 
Create Procedure Insert_Genero (pNombreGenero VARCHAR(45),pFamilia VARCHAR(45))
Begin
Declare vFamilia_ID INT;
Select Familia_ID into vFamilia_ID from Familia where Familia = pFamilia;
IF(vFamilia_ID is NULL) THEN 
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' 
SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'pFamilia No not found in Familia table'; 
END IF;
Insert Into Genero(NombreGenero,Familia) Values(pNombreGenero,vFamilia_ID);
COMMIT; 
End  
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

So please help, because I'm about to get crazy!

Thanks.

Comment: Does the error show a line number?

Comment: The error is in Line 7, "SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'